# nested json response to get data form site in python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

```
{
  "updateEpoch": 1584073939851,
  "totalConfirmed": 1743,
  "totalDeaths": 41,
  "stateToCountyToData": {
    "WA": {
      "stateConfirmed": 457,
      "stateDeaths": 31,
      "countyToData": {
        "King": {
          "countyConfirmed": 270,
          "countyDeaths": 27,
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  -122.536993,
                  47.403355,
                  0
                ],
                [
                  -122.537595,
                  47.337339,
                  0
                ],
                [
                  -122.510135,
                  47.31962,
                  0
                ],
                [
                  -122.437252,
                  47.333717
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**expected results** = `county=king,countyconfirmed=270,countydeaths=27`

Code:

```
listing_response=json.loads(response.text)
listings=listing_response.get("data")
if listings:
for listing in listings:
    countyconfirmed=listing.get("stateToCountyToData").get("WA").get("countyToData").get("King").get("countyConfirmed")
    print(countyconfirmed)
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I need to scrap the county=king,countyconfirmed=270,countydeaths=27 i get issue as AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get

Comment: Your code sample includes `listing_response.get("data")`, what does this output? I don't see a "data" key in your JSON.

Comment: there is no key in that response so I wanted to know hw to get the response,

Comment: You already have it? `listing_response` is your response and you should find that it has the `stateToCountyToData` key.

Comment: listings=listing_response.get("stateToCountyToData") how to yield king and othrs countyconfrmd,countydeaths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since some of your fields, such as "King", are likely not to be known by your program, you will need to iterate through some of the JSON and process all child elements. Something like this will extract the relevant parts of your data for each state and county present in the response:

```
listing_response = json.loads(response.text)
for state, state_content in listing_response["stateToCountyToData"].items():                                                
    for county, county_content in state_content["countyToData"].items():
        print("{}: {}: confirmed= {}; deaths= {}".format(
            state, county, county_content["countyConfirmed"],
            county_content["countyDeaths"]))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: same above attached json structure with more  differnt state,countyconfirmed,countydeaths goes i need to loop and get all states,countyconfrmd,countydeaths

Comment: Does that JSON element definitely have the "countyDeaths" field? You may want to consider making it optional, i.e. assume 0 if the field is not present, depending on if this makes sense for your data. It could be achieved by `county_content.get("countyDeaths", 0)`

Comment: https://infection2020.netlify.com/z.json fr this response in the above code i get keyerror:countyConfirmed

Comment: Then you could use `county_content.get("countyConfirmed", 0)`

Comment: county_content.get("countyDeaths",0)))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200b' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You should look into encoding to solve this - likely your response is not `ascii` encoded. I suggest that you do some research and, if you can't find an answer, open a new question about this problem.